# Google Cloud Function - storage trigger complains about returning undefined

Tags: google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-functions

I have a cloud function with storage trigger, I know I need to return promise to end the function properly which I did, but I still get warning in console says "Function returned undefined, expected Promise or value".

```
exports.elementChange = functions.storage.object().onFinalize((object) => {

    var element = {
        name: object.name,
        time: object.updated
    }


    db.collection('elements').doc(object.name).set(element)
    .then(()=> {
        return db.collection('elements').get()
    })
    .then((snapshot) => {
        return db.collection('stats').doc('elementCount').update({elementCount : snapshot.size});   
    })
    .catch(err => console.log('Error when finalise element: '+ err)) 
})
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You actually didn't return a promise from your function.  Put the keyword `return` before `db.collection(...)`.